# Mapping Java objects to Prolog representation

Tags: java, prolog, sat

In java, I have a group of objects that are connected with each other. Let's assume that together they are some **model** and let's call it like that.

I would like to validate that model against some specification (defined as a set of conditions). The condition may be something like this:

```
forall child in parent.children
    child.name startswith "A"
```

There can be bunch of such conditions and all of them must be met in order to say that a **model conforms to the specification**. All of the conditions are some predicates that consist of variables and logical expressions and I would like to treat is an instance of SAT problem.

I don't care about complexity of that solution, I just want to use Prolog to perform finding a proper substitution of variables (if it exists that means that a model conforms to the specification).

I'm looking for a way how could I easily create Prolog knowledge base that will consist of statements that represent the objects creating my model.

Do you have anything worth recommending? Or maybe you can suggest some other approach to solving that problem?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but did you have a look into model checking (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_model_checking_tools )

Comment: If you could include in your question a minimal worked out example, that would make it much easier to attempt an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps JPL could help you reach your goal?

From the **unfinished, error-containing** [docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/):

> JPL is a library using the SWI-Prolog foreign interface and the Java jni interface providing a bidirectional interface between Java and Prolog that can be used to embed Prolog in Java as well as for embedding Java in Prolog. In both setups it provides a reentrant bidirectional interface.

A bit further in the docs, an example to obtain a ContentPane is provided using [jpl_call/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/prolog_api/overview.html#jpl_call4):

```
jpl_call(F, getContentPane, [], CP),
```

Looking at the docs of jpl_call/4, we see that its first arguments can be:

> - a type, class object or classname (for static methods of the denoted class, or for static or instance methods of java.lang.Class)
> - a class instance or array (for static or instance methods)

If you only want to obtain information from your Java model rather than executing logic, you could retrieve values using [jpl_get/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/prolog_api/overview.html#jpl_get3). An example below is shown where we bind the Prolog variable Colour to a reference of a field of a Java car object held in the static final .colour field of the example.class.car class.

```
jpl_get('example.class.car', colour, Colour)
```

More generally:

```
jpl_get(+Class_or_Object, +Field, -Datum)
```

Vice versa JPL also provides functionality for accessing Prolog from within Java, providing a bidirectional interface to work with for executing logic between both languages mutually.

If you are looking for a more specific answer as regards to modelling your problem, it would indeed -as commented by @Boris- be much easier for us would some minimal example be provided showing what exactly you want to reach.

Good luck!